# Multiple Expander have to collapse if ONE is expanded

Tags: wpf, expander

I have 4 expander controls.

When one expander is expanded, how can I make all others collapse/close?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try out following code:

### XAML:

```
        <StackPanel Name="StackPanel1">
            <StackPanel.Resources>
                <local:ExpanderToBooleanConverter x:Key="ExpanderToBooleanConverter" />
            </StackPanel.Resources>
            <Expander Header="Expander 1"
                      IsExpanded="{Binding SelectedExpander, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource ExpanderToBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter=1}">
                <TextBlock>Expander 1</TextBlock>
            </Expander>
            <Expander Header="Expander 2"
                      IsExpanded="{Binding SelectedExpander, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource ExpanderToBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter=2}">
                <TextBlock>Expander 2</TextBlock>
            </Expander>
            <Expander Header="Expander 3"
                      IsExpanded="{Binding SelectedExpander, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource ExpanderToBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter=3}">
                <TextBlock>Expander 3</TextBlock>
            </Expander>
            <Expander Header="Expander 4"
                      IsExpanded="{Binding SelectedExpander, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource ExpanderToBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter=4}">
                <TextBlock>Expander 4</TextBlock>
            </Expander>
        </StackPanel>
```

### Converter:

```
public class ExpanderToBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (value == parameter);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (System.Convert.ToBoolean(value)) return parameter;
        return null;
    }
}
```

### ViewModel:

```
public class ExpanderListViewModel
{
    public Object SelectedExpander { get; set; }
}
```

### Initialization

```
StackPanel1.DataContext = new ExpanderListViewModel();
```

---

## Explanation:

In XAML we have 4 expanders. They all inherit a `ViewModel` (of type `ExpanderListViewModel`) from container `StackPanel` through `DataContext`.

They all bind to single property on `ViewModel` class. And have defined a unique index for themselves using `ConverterParameter` in binding. That index gets saved in `SelectedExpander` property whenever you expand an expander. And using that index, the `Converter` returns `true` if the stored index matches with given index and `false` if stored index does not match.

Put a breakpoint in `Convert` and `ConvertBack` methods of `Converter` class and you will see what is going on.

Comment: You got the solution for providing nice code that worked in my sample test project. Above all I do not want any 3rd party stuff/dll for such a minimalistic behaviour... thanks decyclone!

Comment: @Lisa: If you are talking about `Silverlight Toolkit`, it is officially part of `future Silverlight`. Its maintained by guys from `Microsoft` and controls added to it get added to future version of `Silverlight`. So, there is no reason you should not use it.

Comment: How can I expand 'Expander 1' at the application Startup ?

Comment: While this worked for me, it always thew an exception on program startup. Some of my other code was already using `DataContext = this;` on my main window, so I fixed it by adding `public ExpanderListViewModel ExpanderListViewModel { get; set; } = new ExpanderListViewModel();` to my main window class, and changing the binding to `IsExpanded="{Binding ExpanderListViewModel.SelectedExpander, ...`

It's possible I had something else setup incorrectly, but I thought it might be useful to someone else.

Comment: While debugging, I noticed that when I put the same `ConverterParameter` for all the expanders, I still works (ONLY ONE expander opened at a time). However, isn't it expected to expand ALL of them when I expand one? After putting a break-point in the `Convert` method of the converter, It seems that the expression `value == parameter` is always false, even though the hold the same value... What can be an explanation for that?

Comment: After a bit of research, I found out that when comparing objects with the `==` operator, it actually compares the references instead of the content of the objects. So in order for the code to work as expected, you should convert the `value` and the `parameter` to integers before comparing. As such, the return statement of the `Convert` method should be `return (System.Convert.ToInt32(value) == System.Convert.ToInt32(parameter));`

Answer (score 4):

this is how I did it:

1) added a StackPanel and MUST add a name tag attribute (as this is the master).

> StackPanel Name="StackPanel1"

2) add as many Expanders as you need (1 to 100's if needed) each MUST have:-

> Expanded="Expander_Expanded"

added (notice all have 100% the same wording).

3) no other details need to match on each ( no height's names etc.. needed).

Xaml:

```
<StackPanel Name="StackPanel1">
<Expander Header="Expander 1" Expanded="Expander_Expanded">
    <TextBlock>Expander 1</TextBlock>
</Expander>
<Expander Header="Expander 2" Expanded="Expander_Expanded">
    <TextBlock>Expander 2</TextBlock>
</Expander>
<Expander Header="Expander 3" Expanded="Expander_Expanded" >
    <TextBlock>Expander 3</TextBlock>
</Expander>
<Expander Header="Expander 4" Expanded="Expander_Expanded" >
    <TextBlock>Expander 4</TextBlock>
</Expander>
```

4) To control the open/close of all "Expanders" on the named "StackPanel1"  StackPanel you only need to add the below code once.

VB code-behind:

```
Private Sub Expander_Expanded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    For Each exp As Expander In StackPanel1.Children
        If exp IsNot sender Then
            exp.IsExpanded = False
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

5)Now you can change/add what content, button's, textbox's etc.. you need just do not change 2 things 1, "StackPanel Name" 2, "Expander Expanded" without updating the code-behind else things will not work.

Hope this information is helpful to you.

What's happening?

1) All panels are parents and all controls on that panel are children,

2) All controls are children of a parent panel.

3) A class deals with one call at a time.

4) The class deals with child.

6) The class move to next child.

7) Stops once all children have been asked.

So the pseudo code is like this:

1) Listen for a child’s named x

2)  Ask each child in parents list of children

3)      If child is not calling then

4)          Child is expanded is false

5)      End asking that child

6)  Move to next child and ask again

7) Until all children have been asked

Comment: You might want to explain what makes this answer correct.

Answer (score 3):

Just setting the Lost focus seems to be the easiest way to do this.

Xaml:

```
<Expander LostFocus="CollapseExpander" ExpandDirection="Down" Width="175">
    <ListBox Height="265" Margin="0,5,0,10">
    </ListBox>
</Expander>
```

VB:

```
Private Sub CollapseExpander(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)

 sender.IsExpanded = False

End Sub
```

Comment: The downside of the solution is that when you click anywhere else in your usercontrol/window the expander also loses focus and collapses the expander.

Answer (score 1):

Use MVVM and bind the IsExpanded property to a boolean flag on your view models. When one is updated to `true`, set all the others to `false`.

Comment: should control logic be in the viewmodel?

Comment: What else is a view model for but controlling the view?  As long as you can instantiate and test the view model without needing to instantiate any view objects, I call the decoupling a success.

Answer (score 1):

@wassim-azirar asked to the accepted answer:

> How can I expand 'Expander 1' at the application Startup ?

I added in the ViewModel:

```
SelectedExpander = "1";
```

Because of the fact, that the "1" is not the same object as the "1" in XAML this will not work, so I changed decyclone's answer like this:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    return (string)value == (string)parameter;
}
```

The answer of decyclone was very helpful for me - Thanks.
So I would like to share my experience if someone needs it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Accordion control from [WPF Toolkit - February 2010 Release](http://wpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/40535)

http://www.dotnetspark.com/kb/1931-accordion-wpf-toolkit-tutorial.aspx

**Sample code:**

```
<my:Accordion  x:Name="accordion1" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" SelectionMode="ZeroOrOne">
        <my:AccordionItem Header="First Header" Content="First Content"/>
        <my:AccordionItem Header="Second Header">
            <StackPanel Height="300">
            <TextBlock Text="Second Content" /></StackPanel>
        </my:AccordionItem>
        <my:AccordionItem>
            <my:AccordionItem.Header>
                <TextBox Text="Third Item" />
            </my:AccordionItem.Header>
            <StackPanel Height="300">
                <TextBlock Text="Third Item" />
            </StackPanel>
        </my:AccordionItem>
        <my:AccordionItem>
            <my:AccordionItem.Header>
                <TextBlock Text="Fourth Item" />
            </my:AccordionItem.Header>
            <StackPanel Height="300">
                <TextBlock Text="Third Item" />
            </StackPanel>
        </my:AccordionItem>
    </my:Accordion>
```

Comment: this component is horrible, has several bugs, defects and problems. Is there another that proposes the same operation?

Answer (score 0):

I also needed this, but all answers was too much work IMO.
Here is how I did it:

1. added StackPanel (child align is set to vertical).
2. added 3 Expanders into it. (needed 3)
3. set height of Expanders to 120px to add elements to it.
4. each Expander called ex1..3.
5. each one got 2 events

   ```
   private void ex1_Collapsed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)  
   {  
       ex1.Height = 23.0;  
   }  

   private void ex1_Expanded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)    
   {  
       ex1.Height = 120.0;  
       ex2.IsExpanded = false;  
       ex3.IsExpanded = false;  
   }
   ```
6. reset all the Expanders that should be collapsed height back to 23px at window_loaded.

that it.