# Collapse all the expanders and expand one of them by default

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, expander

I have multiple expanders, and I was looking for a way to collapse all others the expanders when one of them is expanded. And I found this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4449000/wpf-multiple-expander-have-to-collapse-if-one-is-expanded)

### XAML:

```
<StackPanel Name="StackPanel1">
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <local:ExpanderToBooleanConverter x:Key="ExpanderToBooleanConverter" />
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <Expander Header="Expander 1"
        IsExpanded="{Binding SelectedExpander, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource ExpanderToBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter=1}">
        <TextBlock>Expander 1</TextBlock>
    </Expander>
    <Expander Header="Expander 2"
        IsExpanded="{Binding SelectedExpander, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource ExpanderToBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter=2}">
        <TextBlock>Expander 2</TextBlock>
    </Expander>
    <Expander Header="Expander 3"
        IsExpanded="{Binding SelectedExpander, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource ExpanderToBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter=3}">
        <TextBlock>Expander 3</TextBlock>
    </Expander>
    <Expander Header="Expander 4"
        IsExpanded="{Binding SelectedExpander, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource ExpanderToBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter=4}">
        <TextBlock>Expander 4</TextBlock>
    </Expander>
</StackPanel>
```

### Converter:

```
public class ExpanderToBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (value == parameter);

        // I tried thoses too :
        return value != null && (value.ToString() == parameter.ToString());
        return value != null && (value.ToString().Equals(parameter.ToString()));
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return System.Convert.ToBoolean(value) ? parameter : null;
    }
}
```

### ViewModel:

```
public class ExpanderListViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Object _selectedExpander;

    public Object SelectedExpander
    {
        get { return _selectedExpander; } 
        set
        {
            if (_selectedExpander == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _selectedExpander = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedExpander");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

### Initialization

```
var viewModel = new ExpanderListViewModel();
StackPanel1.DataContext = viewModel;
viewModel.SelectedExpander = 1;

// I tried this also
viewModel.SelectedExpander = "1";
```

---

It's working fine, but now I want to expand one of the expanders at the application startup !

I already tried to put the values (1, 2 or 3) in **SelectedExpander** property, but none of expanders get expanded by default !

How can I add this possibility to my expanders ?

Comment: Does the initialization work if you change the binding mode to `OneWay`? If `IsExpanded` is being explicitly set to false during the expander's own initialization, it would reset your viewmodel property.

Comment: When I change the Mode to OneWay, on the app startup the Expander get Expanded but when I click on another one the first when still expanded too :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider what would happen if you called [UpdateSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingexpression.updatesource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on Expander 2 while Expander 1 is selected:

- `ConvertBack` is called for Expander 2 with its current `IsExpanded` value (`false`), and returns `null`.
- `SelectedExpander` is updated to `null`.
- `Convert` is called for all other expanders, because `SelectedExpander` changed, causing all the other `IsExpanded` values to be set to `false` as well.

This isn't the correct behavior, of course. So the solution is dependent on the source never being updated except for when a user actually toggles an expander.

Thus, I suspect the problem is that the initialization of the controls is somehow triggering a source update. Even if Expander 1 was correctly initialized as expanded, it would be reset when the bindings were refreshed on any of the other expanders.

To make `ConvertBack` correct, it would need to be aware of the other expanders: It should only return `null` if **all** of them are collapsed. I don't see a clean way of handling this from within a converter, though. Perhaps the best solution then would be to use a one-way binding (no `ConvertBack`) and handle the [Expanded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.expander.expanded%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [Collapsed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.expander.collapsed%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) events this way or similar (where `_expanders` is a list of all of the expander controls):

```
private void OnExpanderIsExpandedChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    var selectedExpander = _expanders.FirstOrDefault(e => e.IsExpanded);
    if (selectedExpander == null) {
        viewmodel.SelectedExpander = null;
    } else {
        viewmodel.SelectedExpander = selectedExpander.Tag;
    }
}
```

In this case I'm using [Tag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.tag%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the identifier used in the viewmodel.

**EDIT:**

To solve it in a more "MVVM" way, you could have a collection of viewmodels for each expander, with an individual property to bind `IsExpanded` to:

```
public class ExpanderViewModel {
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    // todo INotifyPropertyChanged etc.
}
```

Store the collection in `ExpanderListViewModel` and add PropertyChanged handlers for each one at initialization:

```
// in ExpanderListViewModel
foreach (var expanderViewModel in Expanders) {
    expanderViewModel.PropertyChanged += Expander_PropertyChanged;
}

...

private void Expander_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
    var thisExpander = (ExpanderViewModel)sender;
    if (e.PropertyName == "IsSelected") {
        if (thisExpander.IsSelected) {
            foreach (var otherExpander in Expanders.Except(new[] {thisExpander})) {
                otherExpander.IsSelected = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then bind each expander to a different item of the `Expanders` collection:

```
<Expander Header="Expander 1" IsExpanded="{Binding Expanders[0].IsSelected}">
    <TextBlock>Expander 1</TextBlock>
</Expander>
<Expander Header="Expander 2" IsExpanded="{Binding Expanders[1].IsSelected}">
    <TextBlock>Expander 2</TextBlock>
</Expander>
```

(You may also want to look into defining a custom [ItemsControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to dynamically generate the Expanders based on the collection.)

In this case the `SelectedExpander` property would no longer be needed, but it could be implemented this way:

```
private ExpanderViewModel _selectedExpander;
public ExpanderViewModel SelectedExpander
{
    get { return _selectedExpander; } 
    set
    {
        if (_selectedExpander == value)
        {
            return;
        }

        // deselect old expander
        if (_selectedExpander != null) {
           _selectedExpander.IsSelected = false;
        }

        _selectedExpander = value;

        // select new expander
        if (_selectedExpander != null) {
            _selectedExpander.IsSelected = true;
        }

        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedExpander");
    }
}
```

And update the above PropertyChanged handler as:

```
if (thisExpander.IsSelected) {
    ...
    SelectedExpander = thisExpander;
} else {
    SelectedExpander = null;
}
```

So now these two lines would be equivalent ways of initializing the first expander:

```
viewModel.SelectedExpander = viewModel.Expanders[0];
viewModel.Expanders[0].IsSelected = true;
```

Comment: Thanks, It breaks the MVVM but I was obliged to use this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Change the Convert method (given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4449000/wpf-multiple-expander-have-to-collapse-if-one-is-expanded)) content as follows

```
 if (value == null)
     return false;
 return (value.ToString() == parameter.ToString());
```

Previous content not working because of object comparison with == operator.

Comment: I did that, and put the value 1 in SelectedExpander, but didn't get the 'Expander 1' to get expander at the app startup :(

Comment: where and how you set the value to SelectedExpander?

Comment: I already implemented INotifyPropertyChanged in the ViewModel, and added OnPropertyChanged in the SelectedExpander. I tested it by adding a breakpoint and the value gets changed in the ViewModel but the View don't get the changes !

Comment: For me it is working as you expected only with the Converter changes. Not even added INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: It's no working with ot without INotifyPropertyChanged

Answer (score 0):

I created an WPF project with just your code, having the `StackPanel` as the content of the `MainWindow` and invoking your *Initialization* code after calling `InitializeComponent()` in `MainWindow()` and works like a charm by simply removing

```
return (value == parameter);
```

from your `ExpanderToBooleanConverter.Convert`. Actually @Boopesh [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21304581/3042204) works too. Even if you do

```
return ((string)value == (string)parameter);
```

it works, but in that case only string values are supported for `SelectedExpander`.

I'd suggest you to try again those other returns in your `Convert` and if it doesn't work, your problem may be in your initialization code. It is possible that you are setting `SelectedExpander` before the components have been properly initialized.

Comment: nmclean's commebt helped. I had to change the Mode to "OneWay", it worked but I don't know why !

Comment: Edit : It's not working, because now, when I click on another Expander the opened one don't get collapsed :(

Comment: @Schneider you need `TwoWay` so that the `Converter` is executed accordingly. Do you have any other logic regarding `SelectedExpander` (for instance handling its `OnPropertyChanged` event)?

Comment: @Schneider Changing to `OneWay` was only to narrow down the issue. You're still going to need a `TwoWay` binding to update the viewmodel when a user clicks the expander.

Answer (score 0):

I have wrote an example code which demonstrate how to achive what you want.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <RadioButton GroupName="group">
                    <RadioButton.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <Expander Header="{Binding Path=Header}" Content="{Binding Path=Content}" 
                                      IsExpanded="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Path=IsChecked}" />
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </RadioButton.Template>
                </RadioButton>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

The model looks like so:

```
public class Model
{
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

And the ViewModel expose the model to the view:

```
public IList<Model> Items
    {
        get
        {
            IList<Model> items = new List<Model>();
            items.Add(new Model() { Header = "Header 1", Content = "Header 1 content" });
            items.Add(new Model() { Header = "Header 2", Content = "Header 2 content" });
            items.Add(new Model() { Header = "Header 3", Content = "Header 3 content" });

            return items;
        }
    }
```

If you dont wont to create a view model (Maybe this is a static) you can use the x:Array markup extension.

you can find example [here](http://zamjad.wordpress.com/2009/09/30/using-custom-class-in-xaml/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the property after the view is [Loaded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.loaded%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

### XAML

```
<Window x:Class="UniformWindow.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local ="clr-namespace:UniformWindow"
        Title="MainWindow" Loaded="Window_Loaded">

   <!- your XAMLSnipped goes here->

</Window>
```

### Codebehind

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ExpanderListViewModel vm = new ExpanderListViewModel();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        StackPanel1.DataContext = vm;
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        vm.SelectedExpander = "2";

    }
}
```

### IValueConverter

```
public class ExpanderToBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // to prevent NullRef
        if (value == null || parameter == null)
            return false;

        var sValue = value.ToString();
        var sparam = parameter.ToString();

        return (sValue == sparam);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (System.Convert.ToBoolean(value)) return parameter;
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this

```
<StackPanel Name="StackPanel1">
    <Expander Header="Expander 1" Expanded="Expander_Expanded">
        <TextBlock>Expander 1</TextBlock>
    </Expander>
    <Expander Header="Expander 2" Expanded="Expander_Expanded">
        <TextBlock>Expander 2</TextBlock>
    </Expander>
    <Expander Header="Expander 3" Expanded="Expander_Expanded" >
        <TextBlock>Expander 3</TextBlock>
    </Expander>
    <Expander Header="Expander 4" Expanded="Expander_Expanded" >
        <TextBlock>Expander 4</TextBlock>
    </Expander>
</StackPanel>


private void Expander_Expanded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Expander exp in StackPanel1.Children)
    {
        if (exp != sender)
        {
            exp.IsExpanded = false;
        }
    }
}
```