# Expander Control - UWP

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have an expander control in my UWP app with the following code:

```
<Expander
     Header="A"
     IsExpanded =" True">
     <TextBlock
       Text="Content in A"/>
</Expander>
<Expander
     Header="B">
     <TextBlock
       Text="Content in B"/>
</Expander>
```

Currently expander A is expanded by default and B is closed. However, when I expand B, A is also open. I would like the behavior that if I expand one , the other closes and vice versa. Any suggestions as to how I can achieve this in an MVVM way ? Would i need to use converters here? I looked into [Collapse all the expanders and expand one of them by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21303697/collapse-all-the-expanders-and-expand-one-of-them-by-default) but most of the solutions happen to be in modifying the code behind. How do i achieve the same if i have a XAML  code in Main.xaml and i have a corresponding  MainPageViewModel.cs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like the behavior that if I expand one , the other closes and vice versa.

For this scenario, you could use `OppositConverter` to make the other expender close when previous is open.

```
public class OppositConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
  
        return !(bool)value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return !(bool)value;
    }
}
public class MainPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainPageViewModel()
    {

    }
    private bool _isExpend;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
    public bool IsExpend
    {
        get
        {
            return _isExpend;
        }
        set
        {
            _isExpend = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <local:MainPageViewModel x:Name="ViewModel" />
</Page.DataContext>
<Page.Resources>
    <local:OppositConverter x:Key="OppositConverter" />
</Page.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <controls:Expander
        x:Name="Expander1"
        Margin="0,0,0,10"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
        ExpandDirection="Down"
        Header="This is the header - expander 1"
        IsExpanded="{Binding IsExpend, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Text="This is the expanded content"
                TextWrapping="Wrap" />
        </Grid>
    </controls:Expander>
    <controls:Expander
        x:Name="Expander2"
        Margin="0,0,0,10"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
        ExpandDirection="Down"
        Header="This is the header - expander 2"
        IsExpanded="{Binding IsExpend, Converter={StaticResource OppositConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Text="This is the expanded content"
                TextWrapping="Wrap" />
        </Grid>
    </controls:Expander>     
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Thank you Nico for this example. I modified the above code as follows to get the desired output. In public class MainPageViewModel, i used set { isExpend=value; RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(isExpend))}  instead of the onPropertyChanged method. I also modified the xaml file such that the first expander uses the converter and not the second. What is the difference between using the method over  RaisePropertyChanged ? When is ConvertBack called here ?

Comment: There is no difference between `RaisePropertyChanged`  and `OnPropertyChanged`. both of them could notify ui update when the property changed. And the only diffecnece is  `OnPropertyChanged` will get the property name automatically.

Comment: ConvertBack Modifies the target data before passing it to the source object. This method is called only in TwoWay bindings.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. Can i get help understanding the flow of this code? When is convertback code called here ? when the first expander is open and the second expander is collapsed, and user clicks to open the second expander, how does the first expander collapse ?

Comment: Yep, the two expanders binding the same `IsExpend` property.  but the second use Converter to get opposition. when we click the second one `IsExpend` will become true, and this behaviour will invoke  `ConvertBack` method to return false.  And at this time `IsExpend` value (false) changing will effect the first expander.

Comment: Please check[data binding in depth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth) official document .

Comment: Yes!! Thank you for all your help